# Google OAuth via gapi.signin2.render button not hitting callbacks in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, google-signin

I have the Google Signin Button properly rendering inside my react component using the `gapi.signin2.render` method on the latest Google platform web-client api (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js).

But, for the life of me, I can't get it to properly call my success or failure callbacks.

The button renders, clicking the button opens the account auth window, clicking a Google account closes the window, but no callback.

```
function myCallback(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
  width: 200,
  height: 50,
  longtitle: true,
  theme: 'dark',
  onsuccess: myCallback,
  onfailure: myCallback
});
```

I have no clue what I'm missing here. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey. I'm having a very similar issue with Angular. Did you get any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#add_a_google_sign-in_button) tell you to add this:

`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>`

But that won't work with React. I found that removing `data-onsuccess` and `class` (`className`) from the `div` did the trick. So if you have something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.gapi.signin2.render('gs2', {
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
      'width': 200,
      'height': 50,
      'longtitle': true,
      'theme': 'dark',
      'onsuccess': onGoogleSignIn
    });
  }, []);

  const onGoogleSignIn = user => {
    console.log('user', user);
  }
```

then your jsx for the google button can simply be this:

`<div id="gs2"></div>`

note that I removed the `class` and added `id` because [`gapi.signin2.render`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapisignin2renderid_options) is looking for an `id`.

The caveat is that now you lose the styling. Unfortunately, adding`className="g-signin2"` back to the `div` actually breaks the callbacks.

Comment: can i know how to make it full width? i tried '100%' but it doesn't work

Comment: @abunehneh Sorry, not sure. I would check out their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your client ID you set your url to , let us say 'localhost'. Now you running you code on, let us say 'localhost:8080'.
your 'myCallback' is not running because there is no data coming back from google api, the data is sent to the trusted url that you specified which is 'localhost'.
The idea is simple, the request can come from anywhere, but google api is sending the data to your trusted url as a security step, if the request is coming from there you get it, if it is not someone is trying to hack using your client ID.

Comment: localhost is actually used as an example in the Google docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow