# gapi.signin2.render doesn't call onsuccess method in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, google-signin

I'm using gapi.signin2.render to create a custom Google Sign in button in Angular. The same code worked in another project previously but it's not working now and can't figure out why.
My code looks like this

index.html

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
...
<div ng-controller="loginController">
  <google-sign-in-button button-id="uniqueid" options="googleOptions"></google-sign-in-button>
</div>
```

loginController.js

```
function loginController($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.googleOptions = {
        'width': 200,
        'height': 50,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': success,
        'onfailure': function () {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.googleOptions); //prints out options
}

function success(response) {
    var AUTH_TOKEN = response.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    $rootScope.AUTH_TOKEN = AUTH_TOKEN;
    console.log('Google token successfully retrieved for user ->', $rootScope.AUTH_TOKEN);
}
```

and the directive:

```
function googleSignInButton() {
    return {
        scope: {
            buttonId: '@',
            options: '&'
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var div = element.find('div')[0];
            div.id = attrs.buttonId;
            // console.log(`div.id --> ${div.id}`);

            console.log(`Google options inside google sign in directive: ${scope.options()}`);
            console.log(scope.options());
            console.log('div.id->',div.id);
            gapi.signin2.render(div.id, scope.options()); //render a google button, first argument is an id, second options
            // debugger;
        }
    };
}
```

I found this code snippet from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625970/google-signin-button-in-angularjs-sometimes-does-not-show-up) a while ago and it worked just fine. I don't know why it's not hitting the callbacks now.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420497/7363750

You should already know about this kind of secure authentication or you never think about it,

and it is not documented by google :)